# How to prevent the bot from responding to the admin in Pyrogram

Tags: pyrogram

@app.on_message(filters.private & filters.user != ADMIN)
def something(app, message):
doSomething()

Answer (score 0):

I Expect ADMIN is the chat_id of Admin

```
ADMIN=849816969
@app.on_message(filters.private & ~filters.user(ADMIN))
def something(app, message):
    doSomething()
```

If More than one admin

```
ADMIN=[849816969, 599815969, 488681569]
@app.on_message(filters.private & ~filters.user(ADMIN))
def something(app, message):
    doSomething()
```

here ~ work as not operator

you can find it in Pyrogram Docs: https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/use-filters#combining-filters

```
Use ~ to invert a filter (behaves like the not operator).

Use & and | to merge two filters (behave like and, or operators respectively).
```